# Removing duplicate dataframes in a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a list in python that contains duplicate dataframes. The goal is to remove these duplicate dataframes in whole. Here is some code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
##Creating Dataframes
data1_1 =[[1,2018,80], [2,2018,70]]

data1_2 =  [[1,2017,77], [3,2017,62]]


df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1_1, columns = ['ID', 'Year', 'Score'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data1_2, columns = ['ID', 'Year', 'Score'])


###Creating list with duplicates
all_df_list = [df1,df1,df1,df2,df2,df2]
```

The desired result is this:

```
###Desired results
desired_list = [df1,df2]
```

Is there a way to remove any duplicated dataframes within a python list?

Thank you

Comment: Do you want to drop duplicates in the list or as dataframe?

Comment: I want to drop the entire dataframe if it is an exact duplicate with another dataframe in the list.

Comment: Since you have the same columns, it would be logical to make one big dataframe out of the dataframes in the list and remove duplicates like Engineero did. But apparently, you don't want that.

Comment: Is it a duplicate if the data are the same, but the index order is different (i.e. just swap the rows of one of the DataFrames)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use pandas [`DataFrame.equals`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.equals.html) with `list comprehension` in combination with `enumerate` to compare the items in the list between each other:

```
desired_list = [all_df_list[x] for x, _ in enumerate(all_df_list) if all_df_list[x].equals(all_df_list[x-1]) is False]

print(desired_list)
[   ID  Year  Score
0   1  2018     80
1   2  2018     70,    ID  Year  Score
0   1  2017     77
1   3  2017     62]
```

---

`DataFrame.equals` returns `True` if the compared dataframes are equal:

```
df1.equals(df1)
True

df1.equals(df2)
False
```

**Note**
As Wen-Ben noted in the comments. Your list should be sorted like `[df1, df1, df1, df2, df2, df2]`. Or with more df's: `[df1, df1, df2, df2, df3, df3]`

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the desired result! Thank you!!

Comment: @Jake just one question , your duplicated always show as df1,df1,df1,df3,df3 or , it may be df1,df2,df3,df1,df2,df2

Comment: @Wen-Ben I was just trying to quickly represent a list with duplicated dataframes within it

Comment: @Erfan if all your dataframes are equal then this will result in empty dataframe

Answer (score 3):

I am doing with `numpy.unique`

```
_,idx=np.unique(np.array([x.values for x in all_df_list]),axis=0,return_index=True)
desired_list=[all_df_list[x] for  x in idx ]
desired_list
Out[829]: 
[   ID  Year  Score
 0   1  2017     77
 1   3  2017     62,    ID  Year  Score
 0   1  2018     80
 1   2  2018     70]
```

Comment: @Jake I mean the one Erfan's method is nice  will check the duplicated with [df1,df1, df2,df2], however, not [df1,df2,df1,df2]..

Comment: @Erfan btw you can fixed this by using `[[x.equals(y) for x in all_df_list] for y in all_df_list]` then find the duplicate and unique with above output

Answer (score 1):

My first thought was to use a set, but dataframes are mutable and thus not hashable. Do you still need individual dataframes in your list, or is it useful to merge all of these into a single dataframe with all unique values?

You can [`pd.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html#pandas.merge) them all into a single dataframe with unique values using [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) from [`functools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html):

```
from functools import reduce
reduced_df = reduce(lambda left, right: pd.merge(left, right, on=None, how='outer'),
                    all_df_list)
print(reduced_df)
#    ID  Year  Score
# 0   1  2018     80
# 1   2  2018     70
# 2   1  2017     77
# 3   3  2017     62
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I do need to keep individual dataframes in the list. Merging the files will not work for my application.

Answer (score 1):

There's a new Python library `pyoccur` to do this easily.

```py
from pyoccur import pyoccur
pyoccur.remove_dup(all_df_list)
```

Output:

```
 0   1  2018     80
 1   2  2018     70,    ID  Year  Score
 0   1  2017     77
 1   3  2017     62]
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass the list of duplicate `df's` to `pd.Series` and drop duplicate and convert it back to list

```
In [229]: desired_list = pd.Series(all_df_list).drop_duplicates().tolist()

In [230]: desired_list
Out[230]:
[   ID  Year  Score
 0   1  2018     80
 1   2  2018     70,    ID  Year  Score
 0   1  2017     77
 1   3  2017     62]
```

The final `desired_list` hold 2 dataframe equal to `df1`, `df2`

```
In [231]: desired_list[0] == df1
Out[231]:
     ID  Year  Score
0  True  True   True
1  True  True   True

In [232]: desired_list[1] == df2
Out[232]:
     ID  Year  Score
0  True  True   True
1  True  True   True
```

Answer (score 0):

I find this easier to read and understand and debug.

DISCLAIMER: If you are planning to work with large lists you need to consider a different solution.

```
def remove_duplicate_dataframes(dfs: list) -> list:
    if len(dfs) < 2:
        return dfs

    unique_dfs = []
    for idx, df in enumerate(dfs):
        if len(unique_dfs) == 0:
            unique_dfs.append(df)
            continue

        dfs_copy = deepcopy(dfs)
        dfs_copy.pop(idx)
        if any([df_.equals(df) for df_ in dfs_copy]):
            continue
        else:
            unique_dfs.append(df)

    return unique_dfs
```